# TLF text word-wrap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, word-wrap

suppose I have added a TLF text named 'testTLF' to my app and it can contain 6 characters per each line and word-wrap is also enabled ... now I append this text to it:

```
testTLF.appendText("abc(ijklm");
```

the problem is that it doesn't fulfill each line with 6 characters but it shows something like this:

```
abc
(ijklm
```

while what I want is this:

```
abc(ij
klm
```

Comment: Careful with wordWrap - it only works on TLF TextFields **after** you've set the text. any time you set the text again it will reset it to `false`! The whole TLF framework is a buggy mess, if you ask me. Most of the methods they copied over from TextField don't even work at all - they're just there to prevent error messages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Properties panel, expand the "Advanced Character" section and change the value of Break to Any.